# Nested ifnum conditional groupplots with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, conditionals

I want to use `groupplots`, and set a variable to conditionally plot the plots. Here is the minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\def\a{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by \a},height=3cm,width=6cm]
    \ifnum\a>0{ %
    \nextgroupplot[title=One]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \ifnum\a>1{ %
    \nextgroupplot[title=Two]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
    \ifnum\a>2{ %
    \nextgroupplot[title=Three]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
    \ifnum\a>3{ %
    \nextgroupplot[title=Four]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
    }\fi
    }\fi
    }\fi
    }\fi
  \end{groupplot}
\node (title) at (0,0) {THE Title};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This fails with:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.24     }
          \fi
```

Not sure if it's because of the nested `\ifnum`s, or because of `\nextgroupplot`; if the first `\nextgroupplot` is commented, error is now:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11     \addplot
                  coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
```

Can such a conditional plotting of group plots be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the use of groups inside the `groupplot` construction. I've added some indentation, and corrected the small type (missing `}` at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` environment):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\def\a{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by \a},height=3cm,width=6cm]
    \ifnum\a>0
      \nextgroupplot[title=One]
      \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
      \ifnum\a>1
        \nextgroupplot[title=Two]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
        \ifnum\a>2
          \nextgroupplot[title=Three]
          \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
          \ifnum\a>3
            \nextgroupplot[title=Four]
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, @Werner - works like a charm! `:)` I used the groups in the first place, because I was afraid `\ifnum` wouldn't work with groups of commands without them - but your solution shows it actually works fine like that. Many thanks!